# How to convert this to laravel

Tags: sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I want yo write this in laravel

```
SELECT *
FROM instructors_availability
WHERE instructors_availability.id NOT IN (SELECT inAvailabillty_id FROM bookings WHERE bookings.instructor_id = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have models for your tables `Booking` for `bookings` and `InstructorsAvailability` for `instructors_availability`, as it uses subquery, you will need to run two separate queries for the sake of simplicity:

```
$inAvailabilltyIds = Booking::where('instructor_id', 2)->pluck('inAvailabillty_id')->toArray();
$instructorsAvailabilities = InstructorsAvailability::whereNotIn('instructors_availability', $inAvailabilltyIds)->get();
```

You could make it complex using inbuild join functionality but I believe its best if you keep it simple this way.

In case you dont have models, then use simple query builder with `DB::table('table_name')` syntax instead of the model.

Makes sense?

Comment: please accept the answer if it helped you so that we can close this thread on StackOverflow. thank you!

Comment: @ra.emi if my answer helped you then please mark it completed so that we can close this thread on StackOverflow, thank you!